# How to cut unwanted text using command 'for' in windows CMD?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a text file which looks as follow:

```
@X ABCDEFGHIJKLM_NOPQRST Y=66 XN=80 XC=132 FONTSIZE=4.0 FONTSIZECOND=3.0 ML=0.0 MR=0.0 MT=0.0 MB=0.0 @x@R111,2222222,222227,22222222,0,"33333333333333333333333333","444444444444444444444444","AAAAAAAAAA BBBBBBB CCCCCCCCCCC D.D||EEEEEEEEE 11|11-111EEEEEEE","FFFFFF GGGGGGGGGGG||HHHHHH|IIIIIII",0,11111111,"HHHHHH II JJ 00/000|||","","","99"
111,2222222,222227,22222222,0,"33333333333333333333333333","444444444444444444444444","AAAAAAAAAA BBBBBBB CCCCCCCCCCC D.D||EEEEEEEEE 11|11-111EEEEEEE","FFFFFF GGGGGGGGGGG||HHHHHH|IIIIIII",0,11111111,"HHHHHH II JJ 00/000|||","","","99"
111,2222222,222227,22222222,0,"33333333333333333333333333","444444444444444444444444","AAAAAAAAAA BBBBBBB CCCCCCCCCCC D.D||EEEEEEEEE 11|11-111EEEEEEE","FFFFFF GGGGGGGGGGG||HHHHHH|IIIIIII",0,11111111,"HHHHHH II JJ 00/000|||","","","99"
```

I need to cut out unwanted text and leave only what is needed.
At the end I should get a new text file which looks as follow:

```
111,2222222,222227,22222222,0,"33333333333333333333333333","444444444444444444444444","AAAAAAAAAA BBBBBBB CCCCCCCCCCC D.D||EEEEEEEEE 11|11-111EEEEEEE","FFFFFF GGGGGGGGGGG||HHHHHH|IIIIIII",0,11111111,"HHHHHH II JJ 00/000|||","","","99"
111,2222222,222227,22222222,0,"33333333333333333333333333","444444444444444444444444","AAAAAAAAAA BBBBBBB CCCCCCCCCCC D.D||EEEEEEEEE 11|11-111EEEEEEE","FFFFFF GGGGGGGGGGG||HHHHHH|IIIIIII",0,11111111,"HHHHHH II JJ 00/000|||","","","99"
111,2222222,222227,22222222,0,"33333333333333333333333333","444444444444444444444444","AAAAAAAAAA BBBBBBB CCCCCCCCCCC D.D||EEEEEEEEE 11|11-111EEEEEEE","FFFFFF GGGGGGGGGGG||HHHHHH|IIIIIII",0,11111111,"HHHHHH II JJ 00/000|||","","","99"
```

I want to do that by pure CMD in windows. I don't want to use any additional software. What is good that text I need to leave (each line) is a regular expression which is as follow: any number of digits,any number of digits,any number of any characters,"any number of digits"

I know that the only solution here is command 'for' but I'm not able to handle this by myself :(
Anyone could help me write a batch file which will do the job?

Regards
Peter

Comment: To me it looks like you are caught in your own restrictions. My restriction is to only help/assist people who at least try to find a solution on their own as [SO] isn't a script writing service.

Comment: Helping implies that you did some work on your own; just asking for code is off-topic here! Please read the [tour] and learn [ask]! Is `@R` the last portion of the string part zou want to remove?

Comment: OK. This is the most value answer on all kind of forums.
Why are you wasting your value time to give a comment like this?
Does it help you?
What you want me to do before I can get some help?
Do you want me to share the story of my life? I’m not a specialist, this is only some kind of a hobby.
I write only very simple batch scripts but the best is that they do what I want them to do so for me this is good enough.

Comment: Do you want to me to show the whole script that I’m trying to do now?
That script does a few very basic operation with file, there is nothing to show.
But I wanted to add some one more extra operation however I’m too lame to write it by myself.
You should add in your comments “use google” :)
I did, and I found this forum. I found a few examples how to use ‘for’ to do what I need but, it’s sad to say, it’s too complicated for me.
Or maybe you want me to show my lame tries to use that ‘for’ and write something which at the end is doing I don’t know exactly what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works with your sample data but depends on the "@x@R" ending the unwanted portion of text. It wasn't clear that would always be present but, if not, you may be able to adapt it as needed.

It actually depends on the first @ in @x@R and then there being 3 following characters that can be anything. In your sample data they are "x@R".

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /f "tokens=1,* delims=@" %%a in (Test.txt) do (
    if [%%b]==[] (
        rem Didn't have an @ so use the line as is
        echo else %%a
    ) else (
        rem Did have an @ so get the part following the @
        set Text=%%b

        rem then get the rest of the string beginning at the first character past the x@R
        echo first !Text:~3!
    )
    rem Blank line between outputs
    echo.
)
ENDLOCAL
pause
exit /b
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I did start from this way of thinking.
Just to remove unwanted text from first line.
It looks that it always ends with "@x@R".
But, I forgot to mention, yes I know my bad, that sometimes there is also something which I don't want at the end of last line.
So that's why I thought maybe it is easier to cut out a proper text.

Comment: I tested your script. Maybe it is some way. There is only problem with last line if there is something. But I can check last line separately and cut out everything after  ,"99".
Tell me one thing please. At the beginning of the first line there is also "@X", what makes that script takes the other (second) one?

Comment: For the for loop to identify that first @ as a delimiter there would have to be something in front of it. Otherwise, there is nothing to delimit.

Answer (score 0):

OK based on thx1138v2's answer I did something as follow:

```
@echo off    
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=@" %%a in (input.txt) do (
if [%%b]==[] (
    set var1=%%a
    for /f "tokens=1-15 delims=," %%a in ("!var1!") do (
    set line=%%a,%%b,%%c,%%d,%%e,%%f,%%g,%%h,%%i,%%j,%%k,%%l,%%m,%%n
    set end=%%o
    echo !line!,!end:~0,4! >> output.txt
    )
        ) else (
    set Text=%%b
    echo !Text:~3! >> output.txt
    )
)
endlocal
pause
exit /b
```

I know I did it in a very primitive way but it's doing what I want so it's good enough for me.

Thank you very much for help.